# Launching Kubernetes Multi Zone Cluster - Service unavailable 503 Backend Error

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, gcloud

I am following along [this](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/building-highly-available-applications-using-Kubernetes-new-multi-zone-clusters-a.k.a-Ubernetes-Lite.html) tutorial to create a multi-zone Kubernetes deployment on GCE. When I run this command (as given in the blog post):

`curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | MULTIZONE=1 KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=gce 
KUBE_GCE_ZONE=us-central1-a NUM_NODES=3 bash`

I get the following output:

```
.
.
.
All components are up to date.
... calling kube-up
Your active configuration is: [default]

Project: ***
Zone: us-central1-a
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-30021049c6
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-30021049c6/...
ServiceException: 503 Backend Error
```

The gcloud config is the following:

```
Your active configuration is: [default]

[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-a
[core]
account = ***@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = ***
[metrics]
command_name = gcloud.config.list
```

I'm not sure why the cluster isn't coming up. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error without any environment variables, `curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash`. How about on your environment?

Comment: Same error with

`KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=gce KUBE_GCE_ZONE=us-central1-b kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh`

Comment: I have set up `gcloud` to work with my personal gmail account but no environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here works:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23933#issuecomment-206561712

```
Add the following to $HOME/.boto:

[GSUtil]
prefer_api = xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to get past this issue by using a personal account vs a service account. Seems to be an issue with creating the bucket on GCE with the service account.

```
gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

Pick credentials to use:
 [1] XXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
 [2] Log in with new credentials
Please enter your numeric choice:  2


You are running on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine.
It is recommended that you use service accounts for authentication.

You can run:

  $ gcloud config set account ``ACCOUNT''

to switch accounts if necessary.

Your credentials may be visible to others with access to this
virtual machine. Are you sure you want to authenticate with
your personal account?

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think I am using a service account, when I do gcloud init I see my account is "account = XXXX@YYYY.com" which is a Google Apps email address account.

Comment: I am able to launch a cluster by using the web interface and then able to use `kubectl` to administer that cluster, but the script (mentioned above in the question) does not work for me.